# (OSX) Can't run gvim from gvim

Tags: vimscript, gvim, vimscript-python, macos

I make a file called `run_gvim_thing.sh` in my home dir. Inside of that is the command `gvim myfile.py && echo "yay"`. If I run that file from terminal it launches gvim with myfile.py. If I run that file from ex mode it does nothing but echos "yay"

Why is this?

When logging gvim for errors I caught this:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: I don't know why you'd need to start a new vim instance from vim: chances are you are solving a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754) and you should use buffers and tabs. However you might be interested by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/567643) which suggests that maybe you could use `:!start gvim` in command line mode.

Comment: I open a new window for each function that I work with, and I position the windows matching the call stack from left to right. I put tests below their files. I find it much more effective than tabs/buffers/splits when using a large screen. This workflow follows the LightTable ideas. I also have a plugin to open the function under the cursor in a new window which enhances the workflow a lot.

Comment: `start` is a windows only command. On OSX there's `open` but it doesn't handle args beyond the second one even with the --args command. It's frankly broken. However yesterday I did come up with a solution by running a python service with `zmq` and listening for commands and running them. I can pass it the `gvim file.py` command from vim and it'll open it. It's janky but it works.

Comment: Good for you if you found a solution! You could write an answer describing how you did it and mark the answer as accepted, this way if someone else encounters the same problem they can find it easily.

Comment: I've made some more progress towards an actual fix though. I tried running this from gvim: `:!gvim file.py &> error.log` and I got this error in the output: 
    
   `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor Current thread 0x00007fffd35633c0 (most recent call first) Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT Vim: Finished.`

Comment: AND I found that if I comment out my vimrc's python related code (which I should have done to start with) it works as intended and I can open new gvim windows for days. So now this is narrowed down to a python problem. I'll continue after work today.

Comment: I have python3 installed via the python website, and macvim installed with brew with the --with-python3 flag

Answer (score 1):

I put this at the top of the `.vimrc` to fix it. But instead of calling `:!gvim some_file.py` you need to call `Runit('gvim some_file.py')`

```
python3 << EOF
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def worker(x):
  os.system(x) 

def do(x):
  Process(target=worker, args=(x,)).start()
EOF
```

```
function! Runit(command)
python3 << EOF
command = vim.eval('g:command')
do(command)
EOF
endfunction
```

After doing some error logging it was clear that the problem was something to do with python3 not releasing some file if called from a vim instance. So I thought maybe spawning a new python instance from vim and calling it from there would work, and it did.

Hopefully the MacVim people patch this up.